# How to integrate Twitter support into an iOS application?

Tags: xcode

How to integrate Twitter support into an iOS application?

Answer (score 3):

[Stefan Arentz's Twitter library](https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-twitter) is a pleasure to use - it contains the views you need, there is basically no coding to do. Do [register your app](http://dev.twitter.com/) early with twitter and get a submission to request xAuth authentication permission so that you do not have to use the clumsy web-based oAuth method. With xAuth it is as simple as submitting username and password and keeping the returned authentication token to submit a tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

Call `-(void)sendTweet` from your IBAction.

```
// Sending tweets from within the application
-(void)sendTweet {
    // check if device capable of sending tweets
    if([TWTweetComposeViewControllercanSendTweet])
    {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewControlleralloc] init];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Twitting from my iSecret App"];

        self.imageString = @"theSecret.png";

        if(self.imageString) {
            [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImageimageNamed:self.imageString]];
        }

        [selfpresentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertViewalloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry"message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"delegate:selfcancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```